# Two Dim (2-D) array or Datatable in mySql?

Tags: mysql, arrays

I need to store select statement results (multiple rows and Columns) in a variable to use later, Is there a way to do it in mySql only. I want to use it in stored procedure.

I know that single result of a select statement can easily be stored in a variable, but is there any to store multiple rows and columns?

If there is. Then What is that and its Ok.

If not then how a scenario like following is solvable in mySql? I have written following ideal/desired code supposing there exists a dataTbale.

```
Declare dt DataTable;
set dt = select column_name,table_name from information_schema.columns
where table_schema='emp';

DECLARE i INT; DECLARE c INT; set i=0; set c=dt.Rows.Count;

  WHILE i < c
    @q = concat ('select ', dt.Rows[i][0],' from ',dt.Rows[i][1]);
    prepare s1 from @q;
    execute s1;deallocate prepare s1;
  END WHILE;
```

Each Row and its two cells of dt are used in while. Is there any facility of two-D array or some other?

What is being tried to do? Above code in while is intended to display all values from all columns (1 by one) from all tables of a database

What is question? Title and 1st Statement of Question.

Comment: Do you mean like storing them in a temporary table?

Comment: You want to use the column values, as the names of tables to select from? Why are you doing that? That's a bizarre way to setup a database.

Comment: Temporary tables, if you need the result only for your current connection, or in-memory tables if you need them across different connections.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes I think so.

Comment: @lanzz. Yes I am sorry I did not know about temporary table

Comment: @Ariel. You are right. But I need that thing (commentators calling it temporary table) many-where.

Comment: @SamiAkram I suspect that if you posted the entire thing you are doing there would be a better way. But in any case I posted an answer with how to do this.

Comment: Now I think this question was about temporary table or cursors (May be both are same? I did not know about that technique) and this is the advantage of a forum. That I found my question and probably solution as well. So Should I leave my question as it is or Edit the title?

Comment: @SamiAkram A temporary table and a cursor are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing all the results at once, use a cursor: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

Then loop while reading the cursor.

Comment: It seems to me a solution. I will feed back. After having a try on it.

Comment: DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE; Actually i could not understand it. I try to do and then update

Comment: @SamiAkram I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking me.